# How to get first item when populating in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two schemas which looks like this:

```
var SearchQueryItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //...
    'auction': [{'type': mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 'ref': 'auctions'}],
    // ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('search_query_items', SearchQueryItemsSchema);


var AuctionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'id': mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    // ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('auctions', AuctionsSchema);
```

Between them are relation `many-to-one`. The main thing is that when i try to get data from db like `search_query_items.find({'search_query': value}).populate('auction').exec(function(err, query)` i get `query[0]['auction'][0]` instead of `query[0]['auction']`. Is it somehow possible to get first element when populating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var SearchQueryItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
//...
'auction': {'type': mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 'ref': 'auctions'}, // remove the square backet
// ...
});
```

You got an array object because you defined auction field which is an array of Auctions